# Бинарный поиск. В чем отличия пакетов bisect и _bisect?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Чем отличаются пакеты `bisect` и `_bisect`? Мне кажется, что один отличается от другого тем, что `_bisect` написан на `c`, а второй пакет -- на `python`.

Из описания `_bisect` не ясно, чем занимается этот пакет

> Bisection algorithms.
>
> This module provides support for maintaining a list in sorted order
>   without having to sort the list after each insertion. For long lists
>   of items with expensive comparison operations, this can be an
>   improvement over the more common approach.

Comment: Да, именно этим и отличаются. Если доступен модуль `_bisect`, то [используется именно он](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96be3400a97946b0b3d032dd8c3c0561786796f1/Lib/bisect.py#L70-L74), а функции из модуля `bisect` не используются

Comment: @andreymal Это происходит по умолчанию? Есть ли какие-нибудь причины, по которым не передаётся в качестве аргумента `key` как в `sorted`?

Comment: «Это происходит по умолчанию?» — да. // «key как в sorted» — зачем?

Comment: @andreymal для того, чтобы мне делать поиск по кастомной коллекции. Например, у меня есть `Items`, в которых есть помимо целевой переменной, ещё и `meta`. Причём `meta` и целевая переменная сгруппированы. При этом, мне должны в качества ответа возвращаться `item`.

Comment: Ну к данному вопросу про разницу между `bisect` и `_bisect` это уже никак не относится. https://bugs.python.org/issue4356

Comment: По поводу `key` как в `sorted` - я делал вспомогательный класс, который по `__getitem__` возвращал значение указанной функции от элемента исходной коллекции. Немного костыльно, но лучше, чем изобретать свой `bisect`. Кстати, вот он: https://bitbucket.org/dfint/dfrus-py/src/de297cdc58b903a8ff9940156d4f953ee080fef4/dfrus/peclasses.py#lines-307